# How soon before contract end should an intern start looking for a permanent job?

Tags: job-search

I am an intern currently at a museum and my contract ends in 3 months with no option for another contract because it is an internship. My contract ends in about 3 months. When should I start looking for a new job? I don't want to not get a job because I am already committed full time to another until a specific date. I just need some guidance on this issue. 
Thank you

Comment: Why not start looking now?

Comment: If someone offered you a job starting before the end of the internship, is there any reason you couldn't take it? Is there a notice period for your internship?

Comment: @Robin it could harm contacts they've made at the museum (assuming it's relevant to their profession) not sticking out an internship doesn't tend to look great

Comment: @RobinBennett - *is there any reason you couldn't take it?* I can't speak for the OP of course, but in many educational programs, completion of an internship is required to complete the program. So, of course, leaving the internship early could put the program at risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start looking immediately. Employers specifically looking for entry level positions (internships, people just coming out of school, people leaving other internships) understand that it's typical for candidates to have fixed commitments (i.e. finishing an existing internship, or reaching a graduation date) and usually account for it in their hiring processes.

Most employers have a spot on their application for applicants to indicate a desired start date. You can put your date there, and if there are comments allowed, indicate that you are waiting to finish an existing internship.

Plus, if you wait, you may miss a great opportunity.